# DLL Function is not calling from the NSIS installer when uninstalling

Tags: nsis

When uninstaling the software to do the complete cleanup calling the function in the C++ DLL .
To achieve this I am placing the DLL file in the temp directory. Then in the Uninstall section calling the DLL function. But it is not calling the function.

If I place that DLL file in the installed directory then it is calling the DLL function.
But I should not place it in the installed directory because I am calling this function when uninstalling.

Is it the correct way that I am doing? or is there any other way?

**Below is my code snippet:**

```
Section "MyApp"

InitPluginsDir
SetOutPath $PluginsDir
File "C:\Desktop\KillNofificationSoftly.dll"
SetOutPath $Temp 
MessageBox MB_OK "Temp Path $Temp"
System::Call 'KERNEL32::AddDllDirectory(w "$PluginsDir")'

SetOutPath $INSTDIR  

SectionEnd

Section "Uninstall"

System::Call "$PluginsDir\KillNofificationSoftly.dll::KillMeSoftly() i.r0 ?e"
Pop $1 ; LastError
${If} $0 = 0
    MessageBox MB_OK "Success"
${EndIf}

SectionEnd
```

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are extracting the .DLL in the installer! `$PluginsDir` is deleted when the installer finishes. Move all the code to the uninstaller section.

If you are the author of this .DLL you should consider writing a NSIS plug-in, then it becomes just a single line of code, no need for `System::Call`.